# Frequency tables by ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data, frequency-distribution

**Background**

First: I know this looks like [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378299/r-frequency-with-group-by-id) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879551/frequency-count-of-two-column-in-r) similarly-titled posts, but I promise mine's different.

So I've got this table:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","b", "c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"),
                 category = c(0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's got some people (`ID`) and a categorical variable `category` that has three levels: 0, 1, and 2. As you can see, there are 2 IDs who have `category` 0, and 1 `ID` each for categories 1 and 2. Note that no IDs have "mixed" entries for category: regardless of how many rows, an ID will only have the 1 category.

**The Problem**

I'm trying to get a frequency table of `category` that tabulates on the basis of `ID`, and not just a straight count of `category`. In other words, I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

**What I've tried**

I've tried several things based on similar posts, but just can't get it right. For example, this:

```
df %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
```

But that's not quite it: it's getting me the groups I want (0,1,2) but still counting by individual instances of the categories:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
> table(unique(df)$category)
0 1 2 
2 1 1
```

Or if you really want a data frame:

```
> as.data.frame(table(unique(df)$category))
  Var1 Freq
1    0    2
2    1    1
3    2    1
```

Comment: *dplyr* translation - `df %>% distinct(ID,category) %>% count(category)`

Comment: @thelatemail thanks -- Necklondon's solution works too but is a little less clean than yours. If you write yours up as an answer I'd be happy to mark it.

Comment: If Necklondon is happy with the idea, I can edit the comment into the existing answer and then you'll be set.

Comment: Ah good call -- and that's much fairer to @Necklondon, as well. What do you say, Neck?

Comment: Please proceed.